# How do I remove a query string from my URL?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm looking to remove a query string from my URL like below:

The URL currently looks like this:

```
http://example.com/?s=cadeira&dgwt-wcas-search-submit=&post_type=product&dgwt_wcas=1
```

What I want:

```
http://example.com/?s=cadeira
```

I'm not very good with `.htaccess`, anyone can help me with that?

Comment: Are you saying you know the name of the query string parametere that you want to keep?

Comment: So you want to remove all parameters except `s=`?

Comment: It is unclear what you actually ask... If you want to remove those parameters, then do not add them in the first place. a distributed configuration file (".htaccess") cannot somehow magically change the links you generate and publish. It can only take care of _incoming_ requests and modify those. So all you could do is redirect such a request to a URL without those parameters, but what for?

Answer (score 1):

> remove a query string at my url?

The "query string" is everything after the `?` in the URL. What you are referring to is a single URL parameter inside the query string.

In order to keep just the `s` URL parameter in the query string and remove everything else, you can do something like the following at the *top* of the root `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)(s=[^&]+)
RewriteRule ^$ /?%1 [R=302,L]
```

This only matches requests for the document root (ie. an empty URl-path). If the `s` URL parameter does not occur in the query string then nothing happens. The `%1` backreference matches the `s=<value>` part from the query string. Everything else in the query string is discarded.

Note that this will match the `s=` URL parameter anywhere in the query string. In your example this appears at the start of the query string. If you specifically only want to match `s=` when it appears at the start of the query string then change the *CondPattern* to read: `^(s=[^&]+)`. ie. `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(s=[^&]+)`.

A 302 (temporary) redirect is issued to actually remove the other URL parameters from the query string.

Comment: How did you get on with this?

Answer (score 0):

you can split the string at the first & in the URL

```
$pos = strpos($url, "&");
$url = substr($url, 0, $pos);
```

Comment: Where do I put this?

Comment: if you have the URL in a variable use it in place of $url or you can use  $pos = strpos("http://mysite.com.br/?s=cadeira&dgwt-wcas-search-submit=&post_type=product&dgwt_wcas=1", "&");
$url = substr("http://mysite.com.br/?s=cadeira&dgwt-wcas-search-submit=&post_type=product&dgwt_wcas=1", 0, $pos);